# How do I rotate on a custom axis in Blender 2.8?

Tags: animation, bones

I am trying to rotate a screw named "windage" but it is not rotating on the proper axis. I have created an armature and made the windage screw a child:

**Structure:**

[image]

**Entire Model:**

[image]

**If I rotate windage screw on z-axis, it is wrong:**

[image]

**Armature and Windage Screw Alone:**
[image]

The armature has the correct axis to rotate around, but when I rotate it on the z-axis it gets all out of whack:

[image]

How can I prevent the windage screw from swinging out and have it just rotate in place to animate coming out of the screw hole?

Comment: Rotate the bone in pose mode. Hit R then hit Y twice.

Comment: I think we have a winner. Pose mode and rotation on Y. Thanks @FFeller!